# How do I truncate down timestamp in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to truncate UTC time in bigquery. I'm trying to remove the millisecond off my timestamp. I don't want to round down, just remove the millisecond.

````
To this: 2019-11-11 19:10:57 UTC```

I've tried truncate and date but can't seem to make it work.
````

Comment: Perhaps you could take out each component of the date with `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DATE`, `HOUR`, `MINUTE`, `SECOND` and `CONCAT` them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
TIMESTAMP_TRUNC('2019-11-11 19:10:57.181 UTC', SECOND)
```

this will produce timestamp `2019-11-11 19:10:57 UTC`

Comment: how can i convert a column to seconds? e.g. timestamp_trunc(cast(datecol as timestamp) , second) does not work

Comment: @Maths12 - post your question as a new question and we will be happy to help

Comment: Full list of TIMESTAMP_TRUNC options here: https://count.co/sql-resources/bigquery-standard-sql/timestamp_trunc